# Datatables Filtering or searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I recently started using Datatables for table manipulation.

Now i want to do searching on tables with alphabatic ordering...

Please check the HTML

```
<a href="#" class="te">A</a>
<a href="#" class="te">B</a>
<a href="#" class="te">C</a>
<a href="#" class="te">D</a>
<a href="#" class="te">E</a>
<a href="#" class="te">F</a>
<a href="#" class="te">G</a>
<a href="#" class="te">H</a>
<a href="#" class="te">I</a>
<a href="#" class="te">J</a>
```

and Script

```
     $(".te").click(function() {
     oTable.fnFilter( $(this).text(),0,true);
     return false;
   });
```

it works well,but the problem is it using a wildcard search over table ,

Assume that there are values "ASMI","ASKI","ASLI","BISLY","BIKLY","BALUU"  etc ...

when I use the `fnFilter` with `A` as string parameter I am getting values `"ASMI","ASKI","ASLI","BALUU"` because the value `"BALUU"` contain the word `A`,

But how can I do search with the First character :

So when I search with `A`, I need only `"ASMI","ASKI","ASLI"` as search result.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can enabling filtering using regex with datatables.. [here is an example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html)

after you enabling filtering using regex, 
just try type search like ^a or ^A if you want to search the first character with 'A'

here you can find out about [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) (patern)